# How can I construct 2 columns from the same data and compute ratio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with many tables and I would like to create two columns from the same data with different filtering for each. Specifically, I have the following SQL query:

```
select count(*), A.Column1
    from Table1 as A
    join Table2 as B
    on A.Column2 = B.Column2
    where B.Column3 in (
            select C.Column3
            from Table3 as C
            where (C.Column4=9 or C.Column4=4))
    group by A.Column1
```

This creates a table with 2 columns. I would like a 3rd column (another count(*)) which only differs in that there will be a 3rd qualifier in the where clause. I would also like to create a column which computes the ratio of these 2 count columns.
Can this be done in SQL or must I get the data into R or Python and do the calculations there?

Answer (score 0):

Change the case when to match the criteria on your second filter.

```
select count(case when C.Column4 = 9 or C.Column4 = 4 then 1 else null end) as Count1
, count(case when C.Column4 = 9 or C.Column4 = 22 then 1 else null end) as Count2
, A.Column1
    from Table1 as A
    join Table2 as B
    on A.Column2 = B.Column2
    where B.Column3 in (
            select C.Column3
            from Table3 as C
    group by A.Column1
```

Comment: I think that the same problem occurs in this script. Namely the condition I need for the new column is a slight change to the one already there (C.Column4=9 or C.Column4=9 or C.Column4=22). The problem remains how to create the new column and an additional column which is the ratio of the 2 columns.

Comment: I've added an edit to demonstrate how you can count based on two different criteria in one query.

For the ratio, divide those existing values. I'd personally use a CTE to make it more readable.

Comment: The edited version produces the error saying that C.Column4 could not be bound

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ratio of the two columns, then divide:

```
select count(*), A.Column1,
       avg(case when ? then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio      
from Table1 A join
     Table2 B
     on A.Column2 = B.Column2
where B.Column3 in (select C.Column3
                    from Table3 C
                    where (C.Column4 in (4, 9)
                   )
group by A.Column1;
```

The `?` is for the condition that you care about.